# Where can I enable or implement full-line and file name completion in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions, code-completion

In Vim, I love using:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to trigger code completion using local file names.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to trigger completion of full lines from open files.

I'd like to have the same features in VSCode. A Google and SO search did not show me any extensions that provide this feature.

1. Is there an VSCode extension that does this?
2. What is the best way of adding this feature? Should I write my own extension or is there an existing commonly used "intellisense" extension where I easily contribute these features?

Answer (score 1):

The extension [Path Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete) does file name completion.

If you search for autocompletion in the marketplace there are other extensions as well which might provide the line completion that you're looking for.

Comment: Nice extension. Now it looks like it was overtaken by Path Intellisense, but it does the job for me. The completion only works in quoted strings, which is some overhead when editing `.bat` or `.sh` files, but it can be lived with.

Answer (score 1):

I use [vscode.vim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) which is a vim emulator for VSCode. It has most of the features of vim, including the completion of full lines from open files with the same keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.